# Write for loop shorter

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and want to write it shorter. For `!ChangesElem` I have to make a loop. How can I reduce the number of lines?

```js
var ElementArray = document.getElementById('ob').getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < ElementArray.length; i++) { 
    if (ElementArray[i] === e) {
        var ChangesElem = "yes";
    }
}
        
if (!ChangesElem) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: remember that `getElementsByTagName` returns a _live_ HTMLCollection (meaning that if the DOM changes, your list changes immediately). To tighten this loop, you probably at the very least want to use `document.querySelectorAll('#ob *')` instead, which yields a _static_ NodeList (making removals safe), also supporting `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 2):

On one hand, you can get a collection of all descendants of `#ob` with a query string and `querySelectorAll`, then check to see if the collection `.includes` the `e`:

```
const descendants = [...document.querySelectorAll('#ob *')];
if (!descendants.includes(e)) {
  // do something
}
```

But [`Node#contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) would work just fine too:

```
if (!document.querySelector('#ob').contains(e)) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks you are perfect. Really awesome!!!
I like the second answer.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

- You can make it shorter using `Array.some`.

You can know more details on [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var ElementArray = document.getElementById('ob').getElementsByTagName("*");

const ChangesElem = ElementArray.some((element) => element === e);
if(!ChangesElem){ do something... }
```

Comment: Except `getElementsByTagName` [does not return an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) _and_ isn't stable (it's a live HTMLCollection). So at the very least, this needs `Array.from()` around it, but then you might as well use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a static NodeList that supports  `.forEach`out of the box.